# How can I record the date/time when a new row is added?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to add a date value when a new row is added in Google spreadsheet.

I have seen the script on [Add a 'creation date' value when a new line is edited](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51558/add-a-creation-date-value-when-a-new-line-is-started), but I was not able to modify the code to my needs.

Which changes do I need to do in that script?

Answer (score 1):

In [the question you are linking to](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51558/add-a-creation-date-value-when-a-new-line-is-started), the date stamping happens when a new line is *edited*. If you want the date to be inserted immediately when a new line is added, simply replace `EDIT` with `INSERT_ROW`:

```
function onModification(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (event.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") { // <-- This is true when a new row is inserted
    fillEmptyRows(sheet);
  }
}

function fillEmptyRows(sheet) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1);
    var firstColumnValues = range.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < firstColumnValues.length; i++) {
      if (firstColumnValues[i][0] == "") { // Column 0 is A
         firstColumnValues[i][0] = new Date();
      }
    }
    range.setValues(firstColumnValues);
}
```

The script must be installed as an event handler:
Click *Resources -> Triggers -> Add new trigger*, select the *onModification* method and select *On change* from the right-most dropdown menu.

**NOTE**: This does *not* seem to work yet if you have [opted in to the new Google Spreadsheets](https://drive.google.com/settings?id=docs).

Comment: Does this work in the new Google Spreadsheets as well?

Comment: D'oh, it seems not: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M61fnsCRPLaHXRXMMzFMHDHtlJCJsq0ArgJEGSm5Hds/edit#gid=0

Comment: First of thank you so much Julebukk for help but its not working for me

Comment: Below is what i did.

Tools--> Script editor-->Pasted the code-->Resources-->Current project's triggers-->Chickhere to add one now-->then selected onModification, From spreadsheet, Onchange then clicked on Save-->then I clicked on onModication and then fillEmptyRows
 Below error displayed.

TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code").
TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of undefined. (line 9, file "Code").

I have checked by adding one new row its not coming.
Have i missed anything, please suggest ASAP :( :(
I have not changed to New googlesheet

Comment: The script runs automatically when the spreadsheet is edited. Did you press the _Run_ button in the script editor? Don't do that - it will give you the error you're seeing. I have [a working example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avea1NXBTibYdGRBZ0U0YXpIOHdPN1lNVmw2YmJBbVE&usp=drive_web#gid=0), try to add a couple of rows to it, and (after a second or two) the `A` column will display the current date.

Comment: thank you so much, it is working in my different gmail id logins...In my current id If I create new Google Spreadsheet I am not able to see Script gallery in Tools, Protect Sheet, Hidden sheet, Email as attachment are disabled that the reason it was not working.I have to fix this

Comment: See [Google Spreadsheets Scripts Gallery menu item missing](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53324/google-spreadsheets-scripts-gallery-menu-item-missing)

Comment: Referring to your answer "Is this a Google Apps for Business domain? If so, it could be disabled by the domain administrator." Can you please explain this in-details please Since Even-though I have unchecked the new Sheets in "Editing" Tab, I am facing the same problem (I am not able to see Script gallery in Tools, Protect Sheet, Hidden sheet, Email as attachment are disabled), Please suggest what I have to do now

Comment: It sounds like you have enabled the new Google Spreadsheets, which currently lacks those features. See the [_answer_ to the question I posted above](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53376/21583).